# Firefox times out in troubleshoot mode but not with a new profile

Tags: firefox, timeout

My up-to-date Ubuntu Firefox tries to connect to https://velo.toulouse.fr and gives a NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT.

I tried in Troubleshoot mode (`about:support`), so with all extensions disabled, same behavior.

However, connection successful with:

- Opera, Chromium
- Firefox on other devices
- Another Firefox profile on the same browser

Refreshing the cache doesn't change anything.
What on earth causes this?

Comment: For me, Chrome also times out on this website. I don't think that your Firefox is the cause. Perhaps this website is overloaded or is having issues.

Comment: Hum. I tested again, my several tests are consistent, it works and doesn't work exactly the way I described it. Weird...

Comment: It timed out in Edge, Brave and Tor browsers right now. Could be the site's busy, could be it uses browser or user fingerprinting or location to block access...

Answer (score 0):

Often a good choice for testing is using a different type of client, such as not using a web browser.

My browsers time out the same, but as already said, the server is not responding. More detail: The server is not responding to a TCP handshake, so is either simply down, or otherwise occupied.

Another guess: You may be trying to access:
http://www.velo.toulouse.fr/ (unencrypted, not httpS)

Either you have the wrong address or the web server has a problem.